# 人：difference between ひと and -うと

Tags: words, etymology

There are two readings of 人, as in these two examples: 恋人【こいびと】 and 素人【しろうと】

Why is 素人 (among others) the way it is and not しろひと or しろびと?

Furthermore, 狩人 is かりゅうど. Why is the final mora voiced here?

Comment: Other words with this sound change: 仲人{なこうど}, 素人{しろうと}, 狩人{かりゅうど}, 若人{わこうど}, 玄人{くろうと}, 蔵人{くろうど}, 客人{まろうど}, 妹{いもうと} and 弟{おとうと}.  商人{あきんど} is similar, too.

Comment: It is not implausible that we had /karibito/ → /kaributo/ → /kariũto/ → /kariudo/ → /karju:do/.

Comment: What's the question? Phonetics know no law ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This phenomenon is called [onbin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Onbin) “euphonic sound change”, specifically *u*-onbin, [ウ音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#.E3.82.A6.E9.9F.B3.E4.BE.BF), and in this case consists of ひと → うと (*hito* → *uto*), or びと → うど (*bito* → *udo*) with *rendaku,* in some cases combined with vowel changes (these are the same you see in modern forms of historic kana spellings).

The basic native reading (kun'yomi) is *hito* (there’s also *ri,* as in [一]{ひと}[人]{り} *hito-ri,* [二]{ふた}[人]{り} *futa-ri*); with *rendaku* this may become *bito.*

In the case of [素人]{しろうと}, originally [白人]{しろひと} (white person, for “inexperieced”), this underwent しろひと → しろうと, *shirohito* → *shirouto* → *shirōto* (note that *ou* → *ō* is not reflected as a change in kana).

In the case of [狩人]{かりゅうど}, this underwent かりびと → かりうど → かりゅうど, *karibito* → *kariudo* → *karyuudo* → *karyūdo* – note the additional vowel change.

An example that includes a familiar sound change is [仲人]{なこうど} “matchmaker”, from なかびと → なかうど → なこうど (*nakabito* → *nakaudo* → *nakoudo* → *nakōdo*). This underwent the あう → おう (*au* → *ou* → *ō*) sound change you’re familiar with in [お早う]{おはよう} (from *hayaku* → *hayau* → *hayou* → *hayō*).

There are many more details at Wikipedia, both in English and Japanese!

Comment: Very interesting info. Is 海原 also an example of 音便？

Comment: @kandyman, no, the うな in [海]{うな}[原]{ばら} is not considered 音便; it's considered idiosyncratic (irregular), and listed in 難読 in  広辞苑; the うな reading is shared only with [海]{うな}[路]{じ}. The ancient reading is うなはら; it's likely that うな is related to うみ, perhaps a prehistorical contraction of うみ-な, but there's no evidence, and there are many words for "sea" in Japanese for which 海 was used: [kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B5%B7%E5%8E%9F-441091), [知恵袋](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13104681693).