# 人 as a suffix. General rule for a reading?

Tags: readings

When 人 is used as a suffix the reading could be jin or nin (or other readings?).

> 犯人 - はん**にん**
>
> 別人 - べつ**じん**

Is there a general rule to tell when the reading will be jin vs nin, or should I just learn it case by case?

Comment: Related: [Can any nationality be expressed by adding + jin to the country name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61507/542) and [人：difference between ひと and -うと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14073/542)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both ジン and ニン are 音読み of the character 人. ジン is the 漢読み and ニン is the 呉読み (See http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/113338/meaning/m0u/).

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to know which reading to use for all cases since it depends on when the word was imported from China or alternately invented in Japan.

There's also a set of 訓読み to be aware of : ひと、びと、 and うと in compound words. And completely irregular readings like [大人]{おとな}　-- interestingly there's also a [大人]{ダイジン} reading which is less frequent.

One thing I can suggest is that nationalities are all ジン : [中国人]{チュウゴクジン}, [フランス人]{フランスジン}, など

Answer (score 6):

No rule, just case by case.

There are also words like this:

- 素人{しろうと}
- 玄人{くろうと}
- 狩人{かりゅうど}
- 助{すけ}っ人{と}